# Azure Functions crash when attempting to connect debugger, causes nodemon to perpetually reload

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, azure-functions, nodemon

Have tried clean formats and re-installing nodemon to no avail, when running with azure functions and tsc -w without changing anything I get this on loop (the is a snippet there's much more):

> [nodemon] files triggering change check: dist/api/index.js.map
>   [nodemon] matched rule: **/*.* [nodemon] changes after filters
>   (before/after): 1/0 [nodemon] files triggering change check:
>   dist/api/index.js [nodemon] matched rule: **/*.* [nodemon] changes
>   after filters (before/after): 1/1 [nodemon] restarting due to
>   changes... [nodemon] dist/api/index.js
>
> [nodemon] files triggering change check: dist/graphql/es.js.map
>   [nodemon] matched rule: **/*.* [nodemon] changes after filters
>   (before/after): 1/0 [nodemon] files triggering change check:
>   dist/graphql/es.js [nodemon] matched rule: **/*.* [nodemon] changes
>   after filters (before/after): 1/1 [nodemon] restarting due to
>   changes... [nodemon] dist/graphql/es.js
>
> [nodemon] files triggering change check:
>   dist/graphql/databaseInit.js.map [nodemon] matched rule: **/*.*
>   [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/0 [nodemon] files
>   triggering change check: dist/graphql/databaseInit.js [nodemon]
>   matched rule: **/*.* [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after):
>   1/1 [nodemon] restarting due to changes... [nodemon]
>   dist/graphql/databaseInit.js

The VSCode config I'm using:

> {
>         "name": "Launch Backend",
>         "type": "node",
>         "request": "launch",
>         "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
>         "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
>         "runtimeArgs": [
>           "--inspect=5858",
>           "--verbose"
>         ],
>         "restart": true,
>         "port": 5858,
>         "console": "integratedTerminal",
>         "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
>       },

and package.json:

> "scripts": {
>       "build": "tsc",
>       "watch": "tsc -w",
>       "prestart": "npm run build && func extensions install",
>       "start:host": "func start --cors *",
>       "start": "npm run start:host & npm run watch",
>       "build:production": "npm run prestart && npm prune --production",
>       "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""   },

This does not happen in bootcamp where it behaves as expected, I have disabled cloud synching for documents where these files are.

**Update**

> Geting this when I just run  the base command bypassing nodemon:
>
> 29/04/2020 14:56:36] Host initialized (45ms) [29/04/2020 14:56:36]
>   Host started (46ms) [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Job host started [29/04/2020
>   14:56:36] Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5859 failed: address already
>   in use [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Starting worker process:node 
>   --inspect=5859 "/Users/ahmed/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js"
>   --host 127.0.0.1 --port 53018 --workerId b6aaf934-a647-46b0-8bde-35ef8584b03a --requestId
>   ef307ac9-edc9-440b-8735-e81f1879029f --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
>   [29/04/2020 14:56:36] node process with Id=11410 started [29/04/2020
>   14:56:36] Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5859 failed: address already
>   in use [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Starting worker process:node 
>   --inspect=5859 "/Users/ahmed/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.2/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js"
>   --host 127.0.0.1 --port 53018 --workerId c12804a8-bb18-485c-95e0-c516c6fc4599 --requestId
>   c93e0c56-cdf0-4360-869b-d6410005227f --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
>   [29/04/2020 14:56:36] node process with Id=11411 started [29/04/2020
>   14:56:36] Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5859 failed: address already
>   in use [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Exceeded language worker restart retry
>   count for runtime:node. Shutting down Functions Host [29/04/2020
>   14:56:36] Stopping host... [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Stopping JobHost
>   [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Job host stopped [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Host
>   shutdown completed. [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Host restarted. [29/04/2020
>   14:56:36] Stopping JobHost [29/04/2020 14:56:36] Job host stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much more debugging I found the issue had to do with my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "start:host": "func start --cors *",
    "start": "npm run start:host & npm run watch",
  },
```

Looks like & nom run watch was killing the process in macOS for whatever reason. Since npm run watch never really worked even on windows (always had to do a seperate tsc -w in the folder to get recompiling working) I decided to just remove eit.

If someone can explain why or propose a better fix I'm very open to that as this is a very tacky solution.

Answer (score 3):

`nodemon` requires you to specify which files you want to watch, elseway it will check anything in the cwd. You can use the `--watch` flag, i.e. `--watch dist/`